# How to stop CSS cascading or how to target only 2nd child and not 3rd with CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've three containers, like so

```
container
  |
  + container
      |
      + container
```

I want to minisize the middle container by applying class "minisized". However, this also minisizes the third container.

Is it possible to target only the second container and not the third? I would like to add a class to embedded or to container, but not to the individual rows if possible.

--------------------------- update ---------------------------

I was able to make both Tarun's and Imashcha's answer work.

Code below was updated according to answer of Imashcha.

--------------------------- update ---------------------------

```
<style type="text/css">

    .container
    {
        border-width: 10px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: rgb(0,0,255);

        margin: 10px;
    }

    .container .row
    {
        border-width: 2px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: rgb(255,128,0);
    }

    .container.minisized>.row1 { display: block;}
    .container.minisized>.row2 { display: none;}
    .container.minisized>.row3 { display: none;}
    .container.minisized>.row4 { display: none;}

</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row row1">row 1</div>
    <div class="row row2">row 2</div>
    <div class="row row3">row 3</div>
    <div class="embedded">
        <div class="container minisized"> <!-- "container" --> <!-- "container minisized" -->
            <div class="row row1">row 1</div>
            <div class="row row2">row 2</div>
            <div class="row row3">row 3</div>
            <div class="embedded">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row row1">row 1</div>
                    <div class="row row2">row 2</div>
                    <div class="row row3">row 3</div>
                    <div class="embedded">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row row4">row 4</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row row4">row 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row4">row 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is unclear whether you are satisfied with the solution; did it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are referring to all `.rowX` children of the `.embedded.minisized`.
To access only the container's direct children, use the following:

```
    .embedded.minisized>.container>.row1 { display: block;}
    .embedded.minisized>.container>.row2 { display: none;}
    .embedded.minisized>.container>.row3 { display: none;}
    .embedded.minisized>.container>.row4 { display: none;}
```

Comment: I don't think it will work as you are not considering the container class inside .embedded.minisized

Comment: I've accepted Imashcha answer, but the answer was changed later. Please see Tarun's answer.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easiest to go for adding a new class and styling accordingly.

If that's not an option, given your markup, you need some weird selector like so:

```
body(assuming body is above your first container in DOM) > .container > .embedded > .container { //minisize rules }
```

That way you target the direct children in that specific order
You could also add your new class to the middle one in JS but that just makes your render all jumpy.

Answer (score 1):

The css is getting applied on all the children inside .embedded.minisized
You have to apply css on the immediate child. use ">" css selector for selecting immediate child. Use the below CSS:-

```
        .container .embedded.minisized > .comtainer > .row1 { display: block;}
        .container .embedded.minisized > .container > .row2 { display: none;}
        .container .embedded.minisized > .container > .row3 { display: none;}
        .container .embedded.minisized > .container > .row4 { display: none;}
```

Comment: Your answer is a more specific answer to the question, but I was able to make Imashcha answer work first, which is why I accepted it.

Comment: Ok no problem. What matters is that you solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I think [nth-child()](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) selector could be interisting

Comment: Maybe relevant to the title of the question, but no to the content of it. `nth-child()` is for children on the same level, rather than on nested levels.